# Large object heap and IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using .Net 4.0 and i need to create a lot of images during my program works. As far as i understand images stored in LOH. Is Image.Dispose() method release memory in LOH? I tried to use profiler and i saw a lot of SOH cleans by GC, but memory usage of application still increase. And all memory releases only on if i call

```
GC.Collect(); 
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

So it looks like dispose method of image doesn't release LOH memory.

Comment: `IDisposable` has *almost nothing* (at least directly) to do with the GC, so basically: no. Note also that the GC doesn't *even attempt* to aggressively hand memory back to the OS for no reason. What makes you think there is a problem?

Comment: @MarcGravell I did some stress test for my app and i see, that a memory usage increase during this test. Profiling gets nothing because all memory releases when i do snapshot. So i think, that problem with my images, that stored in LOH. This leads to out of memory exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IDisposable` is a mechanism of managing the lifetime of *unmanaged* resources (either unmanaged memory or other things, like file handles). The LOH is for managed memory. So yes, calling `Dispose` will most likely do nothing at all to your managed heap usage since the two things have nothing in common.